# Search on Ruby On Rails 4 [Help]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Newbie on RoR. I want to search division, category and brand (by name, not by id). I have a problem to figure out a search function. Hopefully I can get out from my problem. What should I do to convert (division_id) --> (division_name), etc?

```
**#Model**

item.rb :
  belongs_to :division
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :brand

  def self.search(params)
    items = Item.all
    items = items.where("division_id BETWEEN #{params[:division_from].to_i} AND #{params[:division_to].to_i}") if params[:division_from].present?  
    items = items.where("category_id BETWEEN #{params[:category_from].to_i} AND #{params[:category_to].to_i}") if params[:category_from].present?  
    items = items.where("brand_id BETWEEN #{params[:brand_from].to_i} AND #{params[:brand_to].to_i}") if params[:brand_from].present? 
  end

category.rb :
  has_many = items

division.rb :
  has_many = items

brand.rb :
    has_many = items

**#View**

items- index.html.erb

  <fieldset><legend>Filter</legend></fieldset>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <%= form_tag search_items_path, class: "form-horizontal bucket-form", remote: true do %>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="text-field">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <td>Division</td>
                    <div class="input-group input-large">
                       <%= text_field_tag 'division_from','', class: "form-control dpd1" %>
                       <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
                       <%= text_field_tag 'division_to','', class: "form-control dpd1" %>
                    </div>
                  <td>Category</td>
                    <div class="input-group input-large">
                       <%= text_field_tag 'category_from','', class: "form-control dpd1" %>
                       <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
                       <%= text_field_tag 'category_to','', class: "form-control dpd1" %>
                    </div>
                  <td>Brand</td>
                    <div class="input-group input-large">
                       <%= text_field_tag 'brand_from','', class: "form-control dpd1" %>
                       <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
                       <%= text_field_tag 'brand_to','', class: "form-control dpd1" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>

**#Controller**

items_controller.rb :
   def search
     @items = Item.search(params)
     respond_to do |format|
       format.js
     end
   end
```

If I execute my code, I have search by id (not by name).. Thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. first, if you want to search only one division-category-brand, change the view for every item only one text input (but its better to use select/multiselect).

Using text input:

- only one text input per class 
  e.g. `<%= text_field_tag 'brand','', class: "form-control dpd1" %>`
- in the item.rb change the search method to this

`def self.search(params)
        items = Item.all
        items = items.where(division_id:Division.find_by_name(params[:division])) if params[:division].present?
        items = items.where(category_id:Category.find_by_name(params[:category])) if params[:category].present?  items = items.where(brand_id:Brand.find_by_name(params[:brand])) if params[:division].present?
end`

It will not work when you're not filling the correct name in the view, so i suggest to use select/multiselect.
I hope it will work.

Comment: This is a search function like i mean :

Comment: Division : ________ to ________ , etc :)

Comment: You want to search by 'name' and not 'id'?  Or not?
Then you need to change the Item.search function as I described above.

Comment: Yes, i want to search by 'name'. But how about division_from and division_to? Because I have try to create a search function with a range (from and to). Thanks ^^

Comment: Oh i see.
So. The division has a 'numeric' name? Then you can do it with

`items.where(division_id:Division.where(id: (params[:division_from]..params[:division_to]).to_a)) if params[:division_form].present? && params[:division_to].present?`


If the models are not 'rangeable' (i mean e.g. categories are: 'Animal', 'Book', etc.) Then you really need an multiselect for that in the view.

Comment: Oke, I'll try sir. But in my mockup like this => Division : _______ to _______ ; Category : ________ to _______ ; Brand : ________ to _______ ; Actually i have 3 models in item search form :(

Comment: Work !! Thanks a lot sir :)